# "No ha encontrado mejor momento para X que durante Y."

Tags: significado

¿Significa el siguiente argumento de una película que el mejor momento para aprender a conducir en el caso de Wendy es cuando ella está en el proceso de divorcio?

> Wendy es una escritora neoyorquina que no ha encontrado mejor momento para aprender a conducir que durante su no deseado proceso de divorcio.

Comment: Es una frase expresada en tono irónico. Imagina la frase así: "¿No podrías haber encontrado un momento mejor para aprender a conducir?" Significaría que cualquier otro momento habría sido mejor que ese.

Comment: No estoy tan seguro de eso. A mí me suena más a lo que dice literalmente la frase: que por lo que sea nunca aprendió a conducir y en el momento de su divorcio encuentra la oportunidad

Comment: @blonfu - Yo estoy con Charlie en eso.  Pero para saber de veras, habría que ver la película....

Comment: @Charlie - Me parece bien tu explicación; ojalá y luego la pases a una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a matizar el comentario a la pregunta, y de paso respondo.

Para mí el sentido que tiene la frase, tal y como está planteada, es que desde un punto de vista externo, tal vez tomado desde una perspectiva basada en la lógica, cualquier momento habría sido mejor para aprender a conducir que cuando la escritora está pasando por un proceso de divorcio no deseado, dado que esa persona podría no tener el estado anímico adecuado (para mí conducir es algo que puede llegar a sacar lo peor de la gente).

Sin embargo, esa persona por el motivo que sea ha encontrado en ese momento la ocasión perfecta para aprender a conducir. Por tanto, con la frase se expresa tanto que la escritora ha considerado que ese es el momento oportuno (para ella), como el hecho de que pueda parecer que no es el momento adecuado (para los demás), y que cualquier otro momento habría sido mejor.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!